# How to publish Electron app to the app store?

Tags: javascript, xcode, macos, electron, electron-builder

I've packaged the app to mas file for uploading to the App Store. But

1. From Xcode 11, they don't provide an **application loader** anymore.
2. The Electron doesn't generate the XCode project.

In this case, what will be the best solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

***1. We need to generate certificates on developer.apple.com and also need to import into our keychain.***

- **Apple Development** Certificates
- **Apple Distribution** Certificates
- **Mac App Distribution** Certificates (For Notarization)
- **Mac Installer Distribution** Certificates (For Notarization)
- (3rd Party) **Developer ID Application** Certificates (For publishing to App store)
- (3rd Party) **Developer ID Installer** Certificates (For publishing to App store)

[image]

And then you need to download your app's **provision profile** from the app store connect. (Place this wherever you wanna be but need to indicate this in configuration)

You can find create and download the app's provision profile here **https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list**

***2. Need to configure your `electron-builder.` Here is the configuration.***

```
{
    "productName": "your product",
    "appId": "com.my.first.app", //which can be found on your app store connect
    "directories": {
        "buildResources": "buildResources",
        "output": "release"
    },
    "files": ["main.js", "node_modules", "build" ], // include other necessary resources.
    "mac": {
        "type": "distribution",
        "target": ["mas", "pkg", "dmg"],
        "artifactName": "${productName}-${version}-${os}.${ext}",
        "category": "public.app-category.utilities",
        "provisioningProfile": "embedded.provisionprofile"
    },
    "mas": {
        "hardenedRuntime" : false, //IMPORTANT!!!!
        "type": "distribution",
        "category": "public.app-category.utilities",
        "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mas.plist",
        "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mas.inherit.plist"
    },
}
```

**build/entitlements.mas.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
        <string>[prefix (on your app store connect)].[app bundleID EX: com.desktop.app]</string>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

**build/entitlements.mas.inherit.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

(as this entitlements list are the basic one and you can configure as your needs, but the above one is mandatory for publishing the app store. Especially, `sand-box` must be set as Apple's requirement)

After run `npm run build` which means (electron-builder .)
Electron-builder will generate the `mas`, `mac`, `pkg` and then

***3. To upload the app to the Mac App Store. I've used `Transporter` which is available on the Mac App Store. (As I mentioned before on question. From Xcode11 they don't support application loader anymore)***

> **IMPORTANT: Electron-builder has fixed the signing issue from v22.5.0
> So you need to use later version.**

Finally here is the project structure that is working well with the current electron-builder. [image]

REFERENCE:

https://medium.com/@jondot/shipping-electron-apps-to-mac-app-store-with-electron-builder-e960d46148ec

https://github.com/electron/electron-osx-sign/issues/188

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/22656

Hope this helps you so much~

(When the sandbox is enabled app is stopped working. This is normal behavior)

Comment: Any updates on this? Is there still a blocking issue from Electron's side?

Comment: do i have to create electron-builder.json file ? Becuase there is no such file in repo

Comment: Good to create one to add your custom configuration.

Comment: @tpikachu Could you share your entire `package.json`?

Comment: @spartygw nothing special. Which specific part would you like to see?